# In Excel, how can I create a counter to increment based on a condition?

Tags: excel

Lets say in Excel, that I have this in a column. When the number in column N is greater than 3, then the number in the Counter column increases. I have tried if statements, but the count never works.

```
N  Counter
1  1
2  1
3  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
1  3
2  3
3  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple `COUNTIFS()` function.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2)
```

[image]